# converting voxels in DICOM to mm^3

Tags: image, math, 3d, dicom

I am converting some 3D area in voxels in DICOM files to mm^3. I want to be really sure here because I only got the DICOM files and I cannot measure these 3D area that I want physically in mm^3.

In DICOM files, I see that I have access to voxel size, so if, for instance, I got the voxels count, I would go for:

```
mm^3 = voxelCount * (voxelWidth * voxelHeight * voxelDepth)
```

This sounds logical, but somehow I feel that I might be missing something. In DICOM files, there are other information such as "distance between slice", "slice thickness", etc.

So normally, what are all variables that have to be taken into account to produce a formula for such calculation? How do we calculate this?

Comment: Found interesting discussion: http://vtk.1045678.n5.nabble.com/voxel-s-volume-td1225622.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to read section C.7.6.2 of part 3 of the standard that describes the image plane module.  In a nutshell, the PixelSpacing attribute (0028, 0030) gives you the voxel width and height.  SliceThickness (0018, 0050) tells you the depth.  Note that it is possible for there to be a gap between slices.

http://medical.nema.org/Dicom/2011/11_03pu.pdf

Comment: I don't think Slice thickness tells me the "depth" that I am looking for. The nominal slice thickness in CT is defined as the full width at half maximum (FWHM) of the sensitivity profile, in the centre of the scan field; its value can be selected by the operator according to the clinical requirement and generally lies in the range between 1mm and 10mm. In general, the larger the slice thickness, the greater the low contrast resolution in the image; the smaller the slice thickness, the greater the spatial resolution.

Comment: I think (0018,0088) Spacing between slices, in mm, is probably what I am looking for for this "depth". The spacing is measured from the center to center of each slice.

Comment: (0018,0088) Spacing Between Slices is specific to MR and NM images, and it is optional, so you cannot count on the information being present. If you have a multiframe RT Dose image you would be able to get the spacing between slices from (3004,000C) Grid Frame Offset Vector. Otherwise (0018,0050) Slice Thickness is the most general and (although it is not required to have a value) is probably your best bet.